# How can I create test for Activity which is located in the library

Tags: android, testing

The task is very simple but I can't find any solution.

I have an application which is based on my Android Library Project.
Activities are not defined in my main app but in the library project.

Eclipse doesn't allow me reference my library project from the test project targeted to main app.

Is there a working example to see how it is done?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use activity from Library Project, and you already attached it as library to build path, than you need also to put targeted activity in android manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.packageInWhichActivityIs.activityName"></activity>
```

I`m assuming that you are getting class not found exception. Next time please provide more specific information.

Comment: Next time please read the question more attentively. I am talking about the project which tests my application. My main app can be successfully compiled and run on the device. The problem is that my app doesn't specify activities but reference them (as you mentioned)from the library project. So I can not specify them in my test project.